# Using setTexture for animating in Cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Let's say that I got 120 image files in my project. And I want to animate a sprite with all of them.

I was thinking about this method:

```
            CCSprite *temp = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"TheNextSprite.png"];
            [sprite setTexture:[temp texture]];
```

The above code will run like once every 0.03 seconds.

*sprite* is my animated CCSprite.
*temp* is simply a temporary CCSprite initialized with the image file for the next animation frame, so I can take its texture later.

Is that way efficient? I heard that I could use CCAnimate with a CCSpriteBatchNode, but this is only for one single sprite. Plus I got 120 (big) frames - they won't fit in a 2048x2048 texture canvas.

Comment: 120 big frames that don't fit in 2048x2048 … you should know that loading large sprite images is a rather expensive operation. If you have so many images you'll likely run into memory issues unless you release the textures after each use. It'll be difficult to achieve 60 fps even on iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `CCAnimation`, `CCAnimate` and `CCSpriteFrame` classes.

Sprite frames are what you are trying to mimic, a 'piece' of a texture to which a sprite is mapped. They are best used when combined with spritesheets, not all of the sprites in the animation need to be in the same sprite sheet.

`CCAnimation` allows you to create an animation out of a sequence of such frames.

And `CCAnimate` allows you to run that animation as an action:

```
[node runAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animationInstance restoreOriginal:NO]];
```

Comment: Hm, I find that a bit puzzling. So I create an array with 120 instances of CCSpriteFrame? How do I initialize them, given I will end up with a messy 5+ texture files?

Comment: Here is the link for [CCSpriteFrame](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.0/interface_c_c_sprite_frame.html) for information on how to initialize it. You may be able to store 120 frames, depending on the size (I use hundreds of smaller ones, using about 5 2048 * 2048 sprite sheets), but you should worry about how much space that will take in RAM and if it might affect performance

Comment: But let's say that my 60 frames of the animation are in spritesheet1, and the other 60 on spritesheet2. How could I tell when to start using the second spritesheet? Manually inputting it somewhere?

Comment: You don't need to tell it what texture you are using using that method. It is changed automatically.

Comment: But whenever I create a CCSpriteFrame, I am asked for a texture parameter. So shouldn't I need to know on which texture is the frame I want beforehand?

Comment: Consider using Zwoptex or TexturePacker to create the spritesheets for you. You can then use them by calling `[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpritesWithFile:@"mytexture1.plist"]`

Comment: Interesting. So let's say I split my animation in two spritesheets with Zwoptex. I load my 2 coordinate.plist files. But I wonder, how can CCSpriteFrameCache tell *which spritesheet image is the one it has to use in order to find X frame I ask*?

Comment: It expect will keep a mapping of the frames and the associated textures and select the correct one.